# RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT not work

Tags: android, android-layout

RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT not work. (((
it is my Android-Function.
She added new message to a stage.

I do not understand. 
Why my code does not work correctly

```
        private void addMessageToStage(Message message) {

            LinearLayout scrollChatMessagesOutput = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.chatMessagesOutput);

            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = getLayoutInflater();

            View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_single_message, null, false);

            TextView messageTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.singleChatMessageTextView);

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

            if (messagesAlignId % 2 == 0) {

                    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);

                    messageTextView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.chat_input_message_shape);

            } else {

                    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);

                    messageTextView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.chat_output_message_shape);

            }

            messageTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b><u>" + message.getMessage() + "<font color=\"#cccccc\" size=\"4px\">" + "\n" + message.getTime() + "</font></b></u>"));

            RelativeLayout messageAlignLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);

            messageAlignLayout.addView(view, params);

            scrollChatMessagesOutput.addView(messageAlignLayout);

    }
```

It is chat_single_message.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/chatMessage"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:orientation="horizontal"
   android:weightSum="1.0" >
    <TextView
       android:id="@+id/singleChatMessageTextView"
       style="@style/singleChatMessageTextStyle" />
</LinearLayout>
```

It is singleChatMessageTextStyle.

```
<style name="singleChatMessageTextStyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small">
    <item name="android:layout_width">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginRight">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:padding">3dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_weight">0.7</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:typeface">sans</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Do you see the correct background in `messageTextView`?

Comment: Then error in the code: RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

Comment: It must be so: RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

Comment: The result is: http://i.stack.imgur.com/LJf9k.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using two different layouts:

- A layout with the text on the left, `chat_single_message_left.xml`:

  ```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/chatMessage"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="horizontal"
      android:weightSum="1.0" >

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/singleChatMessageTextView"
          style="@style/singleChatMessageTextStyle" />

      <View
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_weight="0.3" 
          android:visibility="invisible" />

  </LinearLayout>
  ```
- A similar layout with the text on the right, `chat_single_message_right.xml`:

  ```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/chatMessage"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="horizontal"
      android:weightSum="1.0" >

      <View
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_weight="0.3" 
          android:visibility="invisible" />

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/singleChatMessageTextView"
          style="@style/singleChatMessageTextStyle" />

  </LinearLayout>
  ```

And you should use a ListView to display each message rather than a ScrollView, ListView's are *much* faster for big conversations.

Comment: I can not insert the code.
little reputation
Link to evernote

https://www.evernote.com/pub/j_dev/stackoverflow